# Change color of column stroke in Google Visualization Timeline

Tags: javascript, svg, google-visualization

I'm attempting to change the stroke color for columns in the Google Visualization Timeline.

I am able to do that but I can't specify that only the vertical stroke lines should be changed not the horizontal lines.

Is there a way to identify just the vertical lines? The svg calls both horizontal lines and vertical "path d".

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['timeline']
});

function drawChart() {
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
  dataTable.addRows([
    [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
    [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
    [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]
  ]);

  var observer = new MutationObserver(setcolumnstroke);
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    setcolumnstroke();
    observer.observe(container, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });


  function setcolumnstroke() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('path'), function (path) {
        path.setAttribute('stroke', '#000000');
    });
  }

  chart.draw(dataTable);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way: Take the X coordinate from the `d` attribute (the first digit after M and the first digit after L) if they are the same, it is a vertical line.

**Regex Answer**

Using regex to match the first numbers after M to the numbers after L: `M(\d+).*L\1`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['timeline']
});

function drawChart() {
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
  dataTable.addRows([
    [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
    [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
    [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]
  ]);

  var observer = new MutationObserver(setcolumnstroke);
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    setcolumnstroke();
    observer.observe(container, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });


  function setcolumnstroke() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('path'), function (path) {
        // Check for vertical lines
        if ( path.getAttribute('d').match(/M(\d+).*L\1/) ) {
          path.setAttribute('stroke', '#FF0000');
        } else {
          path.setAttribute('stroke', '#000000');
        }
    });
  }

  chart.draw(dataTable);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline"></div>
```

**Old Answer:**

Using substring method: `if (d.substring(1, 4) ==  d.substring(d.indexOf('L')+1, d.indexOf('L')+4))`

```
 // The X coordinate of the M (move) command
d.substring(1, 4)

// The X coordinate of the L (line) command
d.substring(d.indexOf('L')+1, d.indexOf('L')+4))
```

Note this would break if it is not formatted exactly as M...L... but perhaps google charts path output is always in that format.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['timeline']
});

function drawChart() {
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
  dataTable.addRows([
    [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
    [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
    [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]
  ]);

  var observer = new MutationObserver(setcolumnstroke);
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    setcolumnstroke();
    observer.observe(container, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });


  function setcolumnstroke() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('path'), function (path) {
        let d = path.getAttribute('d');
        let dl = d.indexOf('L');
        if ( d.substring(1, d.indexOf(',')) == d.substring(dl+1, d.indexOf(',', dl)) ) {
          path.setAttribute('stroke', '#FF0000');
        } else {
          path.setAttribute('stroke', '#000000');
        }
    });
  }

  chart.draw(dataTable);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline"></div>
```

Comment: this is very clever. I tried it on my timeline and I can't force it to fail. Any suggestions why would I need additional checks? Vertical lines look like always have 'M0...,L0' so the way you check for the L+1 should always return ' L0 ', no?

Comment: It always checks 3 characters so if the X value is one digit it will go past the comma and break. Now that I think of it, this can be accomplished better by a regex, I'll update my answer.